# Snapping to vertices in vector tile layer using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, snapping, vector-tiles

I am trying to create features in a geodatabase layer using the tracing tool of ArcGIS Pro. I am able to use other shapefile layers in the project for tracing but vector tile layers loaded from the portal are ignored by the tool.

Is it possible to snap to a vector tile layer?